# recovering xml with photorec

Tags: data-recovery

I am trying to recover some files with XML data using `photorec`. They are in ct format (Cheat Engine tables).

I had them on my Windows 10 system, and I formatted that partition, I've tried using `fidentify` on a sample cheat table and it recognised the file as XML, but I can't find that format in `photorec`. On their website, they say that XML files are supported by `photorec`. How should I proceed?

[image: Here is a screenshot that shows that xml is missing in the photorec settings]

Comment: Is there a "text" or "markup" type?

Comment: @xenoid Ah yes, found "tex?", which is "text files with header", thank you very much, I don't know if I should delete the question or not.

Answer (score 0):

XML files are classified as "**tex?**" (text files with headers) in the photorec options, keep in mind that this extension also includes the sh, html, svg and ics file formats.